# php issues with date validation

Tags: php

Never mind I did not try hard enough, here is what I was looking for:

```
$dob = '1980-09-04';
echo $dob;
$age = date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($dob));
echo $age;
if (date('md') < date('md', strtotime($dob))) {
    $age--;
    echo $age;
}
```

Sorry for the unnecessary question.

Comment: Hint: You should post what exactly you want to achieve and what exactly is going wrong...

Comment: and the what does not do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Btw: If you require the date to be in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, then it is kind of wrong to set the `maxlength` of the `input` field to 8.

Comment: and checking 'numeric' on an input with slashes will not work either

Comment: Would it not be better to capture the date in separate fields?

Comment: And your age validation code is wrong, too. What if a person is 21, but their birthday is in January? They will not be 21 in your system until the next year...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking 21 yrs old.... is this for pr0n?

First of all, MM/DD/YYYY is harmful if you are writing something for use internationally! Better to write

```
<select name='month'><option value='01'>Jan</option>....
<input name='day' maxlength='2' size='2' />
<input name='year' maxlength='4' size='4' />
```

As that won't confuse us Europeans.

Secondly, you're asking for their DOB and storing it an a parameter & var named "age" which is going to bite you on the arse if you every try to maintain the code later.

Thirdly, your example data does not match the required input. You tell them an example with separators and then actually process 8 digits with no spaces.

Actual answer: However, if you want to validate the above icky MMDDYYYY 8 digit string try:

```
if( !preg_match( "/^\d{8}$/", $dob ) ) # fail if is not a string of 8 numeric digits.
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: And your <label> doesn't match your <input> and in the <input> it's  bad practice to have a differing id and name attribute.

Comment: I just changed the code above, thanks for the idea of separating the month, day, year, but I wanted just one variable to call from the php script, $dob?

Comment: Just bite the bullet and use 3 variables!

You're right in using "YYYY-MM-DD" as the internal format. See my rant on the subject: http://blogs.ecs.soton.ac.uk/webteam/2009/11/07/date-formats/